# Comparing two different ranked values in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table:

```
   ID   Ticket_Number   Created_Date   Rank
   123  222             10/20/2011     1
   125  222             10/20/2011     2
   130  222             10/20/2011     3
   133  222             10/22/2011     4
   155  111             10/10/2015     1
   165  111             10/15/2018     2

select A.*, rank() over(partition by ticket_number order by id) as rank
FROM ticket_table A
```

I can get the information to be grouped by ticket_number and then ordered by ID... I do not know how to make sure that the created date is the max date in the grouping with the max id.

Comment: So what is the problem with current query?

Comment: I don't follow what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: The current query will group my data by ticket_number and then order by ID.  I then need to make sure that the largest ID, which is 133, in this example also has the latest date.

Comment: I still dont see the problem. Why you dont order by DESC? explain the logic, what output you want? what happen if the max(id) is different to max(date)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 A.*
FROM ticket_table A 
WHERE A.ticket_number = 222
ORDER BY ID  DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

One common method is to use `subquery`:

```
select *
from ticket_table A 
where id = (select top 1 id 
            from ticket_table 
            where Ticket_Number = A.Ticket_Number 
            order by date desc);
```

However, `top` clause is not supported by all *DBMS*, so use `limit` clause instead if needed.